# Non recursive stack based depth fIrst search in Graph returning results out of order

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

I am trying to recreate a recursive DFS using stacks, and of course being nonrecursive. I have tried re-coding this about four times and am stumped. I have seen a lot of other people working with DFS, but not with this problem from what I can see. The output is:

```
12 vertices are searched in this DFS order:
Chicago New York Atlanta Houston Dallas Kansas City Denver Los Angeles San Francisco Seattle Miami Boston
parent of Seattle is San Francisco
parent of San Francisco is Los Angeles
parent of Los Angeles is Denver
parent of Denver is Kansas City
parent of Kansas City is Dallas
parent of Boston is Miami
parent of New York is Chicago
parent of Atlanta is New York
parent of Miami is Seattle
parent of Dallas is Houston
parent of Houston is Atlanta
```

When it should be:

```
12 vertices are searched in this DFS order:  
Chicago Seattle San Francisco Los Angeles Denver   
Kansas City New York Boston Atlanta Miami Houston Dallas 
parent of Seattle is Chicago 
parent of San Francisco is Seattle 
parent of Los Angeles is San Francisco 
parent of Denver is Los Angeles 
parent of Kansas City is Denver 
parent of Boston is New York 
parent of New York is Kansas City 
parent of Atlanta is New York 
parent of Miami is Atlanta 
parent of Dallas is Houston 
parent of Houston is Miami
```

**Code**

```
public Tree dfs(int v) {
    List<Integer> searchOrder = new ArrayList<>();
    int[] parent = new int[vertices.size()];
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.length; i++)
      parent[i] = -1; // Initialize parent[i] to -1

    // Mark visited vertices
    boolean[] isVisited = new boolean[vertices.size()];

    // Recursively search
    dfs(v, parent, searchOrder, isVisited);

    // Return a search tree
    return new Tree(v, parent, searchOrder);
  }

  /** Recursive method for DFS search */
  private void dfs(int u, int[] parent, List<Integer> searchOrder,
      boolean[] isVisited) {
    // Store the visited vertex
    Stack<Edge> stack = new Stack<>();
    isVisited[u] = true; // Vertex v visited
    searchOrder.add(u);
    for(Edge e : neighbors.get(u)){
      stack.push(e);
    }

    while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
      Edge e = stack.pop();
      if (!isVisited[e.v]) {
        parent[e.v] = u; // The parent of vertex e.v is u
        isVisited[e.v] = true;
        searchOrder.add(e.v);
        u = e.v;
        for(Edge d : neighbors.get(u)){
          stack.push(d);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped me out, a friend sent it to me

https://algocoding.wordpress.com/2014/08/25/depth-first-search-java-and-python-implementation/